# General Fibre of a Morphism of Affine Algebraic Varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, morphism

I am a beginner in algebraic geometry. Can someone help me with the definition of a "general fibre of a morphism of affine algebraic varieties"? What is the difference between a "general fibre" and a "special fibre"?

Comment: I translated the question to English (I think it is site policy that questions be in English) If I am mistaken feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis it is not site policy that questions be in English but it is always nice to add a translation!

Comment: Are you sure it's "general fibre" and not "generic fibre"?

Comment: Yes. it is a general fiber that is involved